# Catching and Throwing exceptions; Why is this considered an anti-pattern

Tags: c#, exception

```
public void DeployCourse(Course course, Client client)
{
    if (course == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Course cannot be null");       
    if (client == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Client cannot be null");

    try
    {
        _ftp.Transfer(client.Server.IPAddress, course.PackageUrl, course.CourseName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var newException = new Exception(String.Format(
            "Error deploying Course: {0} to Client: {1}. See inner exception for more details", 
            course.CourseName, client.Name), e);
        throw newException;
    }
}
```

I've never really got my head around what constitutes "good" exception handling. A quick google search shows that, almost unanimously, people agree that catching and rethrowing exceptions deep in the call stack is bad. Above, I have an example of some code I'm writing. This is pretty low in a typical call stack. I did this because, without this code, it is a bit difficult to find exactly what course failed to deploy. My question is, if I did something similar in many (if not all) methods, to add more context to an exception, why would this be considered anti-pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to reformulate your question to be less about opinions.

Comment: @Alex Thanks. I'll try to change it a bit, however I'm afraid it may actually be about opinions. I know similar questions to this have been asked here before, but I'm just not sure why this is considered an anti-pattern by many.

Comment: No, that's not it.  Programmers that write catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } commit that sin.  Rather too common.

Comment: What @HansPassant, is saying, I think, is that you are not committing the anti-pattern here, because you are not rethrowing `e`.  I agree.

Comment: I believe the real anti-pattern is throwing an exception and then catching it as if it were a special return code instead of a genuinely exceptional case.  Wrapping an exception to give more details is fine IMO.

Comment: I agree that this is not a bad pattern. You are ensuring that the exception thrown is logically connected to the method that was called, which is a nice property for the user of your API.  And you're keeping the old exception around to aid in diagnostics.  There are ways to abuse this pattern of course but the code shown here I think is reasonable.

Comment: What you have would be a mostly-good pattern if you threw a custom exception, but it does have a danger: it does not distinguish exceptions which mean "The operation failed but no harm came from the attempt" versus "The CPU is on fire--run for the hills!".  Your method would thus turn a `CpuOnFireException` which callers would refrain from handling into a `CourseDeploymentException`, which callers would likely handle while stifling the `CpuOnFireException`.  That is a problem, but not really a solvable one, so your code can't be blamed for not solving it.

Comment: Now, there is a bug in your code. The string passed to the ctor of ArgumentNullException should be the name of the offending parameter, not an informative message. If you want a message then it should be (name, message).  **Note that ArgumentException is (message, name), ArgumentNullException is (name, message)  THANKS MICROSOFT**.

Comment: You should also be throwing something better than "new Exception". Make a new CourseDeploymentFailureException or some such.

Comment: @EricLippert The switch of name and message for those exceptions has alwasy bothered me.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you...I've never noticed that switch before hah! I shudder to think of how many times I've made that mistake.

And thanks everyone. I'm sorry if this was opinion based, but the more I read about anti-patterns and best practices, the more susceptible I am to analysis paralysis, and I just needed to make sure I wasn't crazy. What you've said makes perfect sense.

Comment: I think this question is a little bit vague, but there's a non-opinion-based question in here somewhere. I'd re-open it.

Comment: I voted to re-open, too.

Comment: Edit as a question around how to handle exceptions for an FTP connection client. 

I'd say handle things connection failed, file transfer timed out, write failed, file already exists on remote server,

Comment: @Graham I didn't want it to be specifically about FTP connections. This was really just an example. Actually, since I've posted this question, that _ftp (which was of type IFTPTransferer) has become _fileTransferer (of type IFileTransferer) since I don't think this CourseDeployer class really needs to know the specifics of how the file is actually transferred. So, up at this level, we don't even know for sure that it is FTP

Comment: @Kith: I shudder as well. After working with .NET for more than a decade I noticed that for the first time only a few months ago when I was trying to explain argument validation to beginner programmers. Fortunately the consequences of the error are pretty much nothing, since the exception should never be thrown outside of test cases in the first place. Worst that happens is the test case diagnostic is confusing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is somewhat vague, so let's try to crisp it up a bit.

> Is the pattern of catching an exception, wrapping it up in a different exception, and throwing the new exception to the caller, a good pattern?

Yes, it's pretty good. Like any pattern it has pros and cons.

> What are the pros?

It works best when the exception thrown is logically related to the operation which the caller expected the method call to perform. If "operation `Foo` can throw a `FooFailedException`" is part of the documented contract then developers know that they need to be catching `FooFailedException` and -- here's the key point -- **only** `FooFailedException`.

If you apply this consistently then you can change the implementation details of your method without worrying that you are breaking a caller.

For instance, if you require a caller to catch, say, an exception associated with failure of an FTP site, and then you change your implementation to also support some other protocol that throws a different exception, then the caller has to change as well to catch the new exception (or they have to catch everything).  With this pattern the caller can catch just the one exception no matter what the implementation details are.

This also allows the caller to get diagnostic information in terms of the operation that they tried to do, not in terms of the implementation detail that failed.

> What are some of the cons?

1. If the change is made late, then changing which exception is thrown could be a breaking change.
2. Callers might *want* to be catching the more specific underlying exception.
3. If the underlying exception is thrown *because your code has a bug and is calling something wrong itself* then you are hiding your bug and passing the consequences of it on to the caller.
4. Some exceptions are like "the network is down right now, try again later", and some exceptions are like "everything is terrible and you really should be shutting this process down".  By catching everything and wrapping it, you make it harder to know whether the exception is recoverable or not.
5. We have a list of certificates that have been compromised by hackers; we keep the list on the internet. We wish to not use a certificate if it is on the list of revoked certs. Quick, find the defect:

   ```
   bool revoked = false;
   try
   {
       CheckTheRevocationList(out revoked);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       new CryptoException("revocation list could not be checked", ex);
   }
   if (!revoked) UseTheCertificate();
   ```

See the defect? That's a security hole right there.  Finding that needle in a haystack of 999 correct usages of the pattern is surprisingly difficult for humans. (This is not theoretical; I found a version of this defect in real live code by writing a static analyzer that looks for it.)

> Where can I read more about exception handling patterns and practices?

My articles are here:

http://ericlippert.com/category/exception-handling/

The one you should probably start with is frequently referenced on SO:

http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: Is the defect the missing 'throw' keyword or is that a typo you made?

Comment: @Tergiver: The missing throw is the primary cause of the defect, but more generally this is a "failure to the insecure mode" class of defect. Had the default for "revoked" been true instead of false then the code might behave *incorrectly* given the missing throw, but it would be *safe*.